# Facebook API: находится ли пользователь в определенной группе?

Tags: facebook-api

Нужно проверить является ли пользователь членом группы. Судя по постам на стэковерфлоу, простого решения нет.

Начиная с API 2.4 больше нельзя получить список групп пользователя

Можно получить список пользователей определенной группы, если она не секретная. Однако в этом случае его нужно переодически синхронизировать со своей базой.

Так вот мой вопрос заключается в том, есть ли какое нибудь более элегантное решение этой задачи?